# AbstractLoggingActor not writing to File Appender, but writing to console in Java Akka

Tags: akka, logback

I implemented actors by extending AbstractLoggingActor. But somehow akka logs are only being written to console and not to log file, and no error is thrown.

I tried various configs in akka, using akka-slf4j of same version as actual akka version of but of no help. I am attaching original pom configs that I initially used.

logback.xml

```
<appender name="fileAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>/opt/Corp-Async-Job-Processor/logs/corp-job-akka-framework.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>info</level>
    </filter>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date{ISO8601} - %logger -> %-5level[%thread] %logger{0} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<!--appender name="Sentry" class="io.sentry.logback.SentryAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>INFO</level>
    </filter>
</appender-->
<appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>debug</level>
    </filter>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date{ISO8601} - %logger -> %-5level[%thread] %logger{0} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="akka" level="debug" />
<logger name="com.packt" level="debug"/>

<root level="TRACE">
    <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>

</root>
```

application.conf:

```
akka {
loglevel = "DEBUG"
event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]
}
```

dependencies in pom.xml of module:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.davidmoten</groupId>
        <artifactId>rxjava-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.6</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.davidmoten</groupId>
        <artifactId>rxjava-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-http_${artifact.id.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${akka.http.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-http-jackson_${artifact.id.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${akka.http.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-stream_${artifact.id.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${akka.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
        <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--dependency>
        <groupId>de.idyl</groupId>
        <artifactId>winzipaes</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-http-testkit_${artifact.id.version}
</artifactId>
        <version>${akka.http.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.232</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.lingala.zip4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>zip4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

pom.xml of project:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <akka.version>2.5.4</akka.version>
    <artifact.id.version>2.12</artifact.id.version>
    <akka.http.version>10.0.10</akka.http.version>
    <mysql.version>6.0.5</mysql.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.6.6</slf4j.version>
    <logback.version>1.0.7</logback.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-actor_${artifact.id.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${akka.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Logback's [`ThresholdFilter`](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#thresholdFilter) denies events whose levels are below the configured threshold. Your `FileAppender` has the following filter:

```
<filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
    <level>info</level>
</filter>
```

The above configuration means that TRACE and DEBUG events are denied. In contrast, your `ConsoleAppender` has a `ThresholdFilter` that is set to DEBUG, which denies only TRACE events. Because your Akka log level is set to DEBUG, Akka log messages make it to the console but never make it to the log file.

To output your Akka logs to both the console and the file, change the threshold of the filter in your `FileAppender`:

```
<filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
    <level>debug</level>
</filter>
```

Comment: But am not getting even error messages in file log.